# Disable Mock Locations without user settings page

Tags: android, location

I created implementation for checking `Mock Settings` state and I want to know, can i disable `Mock Locations` dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by

> dynamically

you mean programmatically (i.e. by means of a dialog / a piece of code from within your app), the answer is **no**. Mock locations are a feature for developers, so to enable/disable them you *have* to send the user to the system's developer settings.

Before you send users there, you may want to detect whether mock locations are actually enabled. For API level < 18 this is done with the [Settings.Secure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION) flag, for >= 18 you can use the newly introduced [Location.isFromMockProvider()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()). I have written a small utility class that will reliably detect mock locations on all recent (non-rooted) Android devices:

[LocationAssistant - Hassle-free location updates on Android](https://github.com/klaasnotfound/LocationAssistant)

It handles and encapsulates most of the location setup and can also reject mock locations. Maybe you'll find the class handy for your use case.